# Generate Unix-Style MD5 Password Hash in C#

Tags: c#, md5

I am trying to generate a Unix-Style password hash using MD5. I undestand that I need it to look like `$1$<salt>$<hash>`, but the `<hash>` part does not look the same, no matter what I do. Here is how I generate the hash:

```
            MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append((char) hash[i]);
            }

            String calchash = sb.ToString();
```

I am pretty sure that it is now I am using the `StringBuilder` to make a string from the hashed bytes. But I don't know what the right settings would be.

Comment: Unix password hashing doesn't use plain md5. "MD5 crypt hashes the password and salt in a number of different combinations to slow down the evaluation speed. Some steps in the algorithm make it doubtful that the scheme was designed from a cryptographic point of view--for instance, the binary representation of the password length at some point determines which data is hashed, for every zero bit the first byte of the password and for every set bit the first byte of a previous hash computation."

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that I wasn't salting properly either. I did find an implementation of the UNIX `crypt` which works. [http://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptapi/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptapi/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix md5 crypt doesn't use plain md5. That would be insecure, because plain md5 is fast, and password hashes should be slow.

I found a relevant code-project article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Unix_md5crypt.aspx

Comment: This library works better than the one I found above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's about formatting. The Unix password hash is in hex format, while you're writing it down in binary. Replace the loop body with:

```
sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x").PadLeft(2,'0'));
```

Comment: Are you sure? When I look in my unix `/etc/passwd` file, the hash looks different, as it includes punctuation, and other non-hex characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use hash[i].ToString("X") instead of just converting to char. Because hash bytes may be in any range from 0 to 255, which is not like md5 hash is looking.